# could not convert | Erro ao retornar objeto

Tags: c++, enums

O objetivo do código abaixo é retornar os **tokens** de uma determinada expressão, por exemplo: **50+30*(30-10)+(10/2)**. Onde os tokens seriam: [numero, 50], [soma, +], [numero, 30], [mult,*] e assim por diante.

Contudo ao tentar retornar o objeto do tipo **Token**, que contém o tipo (`enum`) e o valor do **token** solicitado via getToken(), é exibido o seguinte erro:

> [Error] could not convert '(std::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits,
>   _Alloc>::str() const with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator;
>   std::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__string_type =
>   std::basic_string, (operator new(16ull), (,
>   ((Token*)))))' from 'Token*' to 'Token'

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Scanner.h"
#include "Token.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    Scanner* scan = new Scanner("48 + 20 * 2");
    Token tk = scan->getToken();

    while(tk != NULL){
        cout<<tk.print()<<endl;
        tk = scan->getToken();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Scanner.h

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sstream>

#include "Token.h"

using namespace std;

class Scanner
{
    public:
        Scanner(string exp);
        Token getToken();

    private:
        string expressao;
        int posicao;
};

#endif
```

Scanner.cpp

```
#include "Scanner.h"

Scanner::Scanner(string exp): expressao(exp), posicao(0){}

Token Scanner::getToken()
{
    std::stringstream valorToken;
    string target;

    while(expressao[posicao] == ' '){
        posicao++;
    }

    if(isdigit(expressao[posicao])){
        valorToken << expressao[posicao];
        posicao++;
        while(posicao < expressao.length() && isdigit(expressao[posicao])){
            valorToken << expressao[posicao];
            posicao++;
        }
        return new Token(numero, valorToken.str());
    }
    else if (this->expressao[posicao] == '+')
    {
        valorToken << "+";
        valorToken >> target;
        return new Token(soma, target);
        posicao++;
    }
    else if (this->expressao[posicao] == '-')
    {
        return new Token(sub, "-");
        posicao++;
    }
    else if (this->expressao[posicao] == '*')
    {
        return new Token(mult, "*");
        posicao++;
    }
    else if (this->expressao[posicao] == '/')
    {
        return new Token(divisao, "/");
        posicao++;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Token(erro, this->expressao[posicao]+"");
        posicao++;
    }
}
```

Token.h

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum TipoToken {
    soma,
    erro,
    numero,
    sub,
    mult,
    divisao
};

class Token
{
    private:
        string valor;
        TipoToken tipo;
    public:
        Token(TipoToken tipo, string valor);
        string print();
};

#endif
```

Token.cpp

```
#include "Token.h"

Token::Token(TipoToken tipo, string valor)
{
    this->tipo = tipo;
    this->valor = valor;
}

string Token::print()
{
    if (this->tipo == soma)
    {
        return "Soma: " + this->valor;
    }
    else if (this->tipo == numero)
    {
        return "Numero: " + this->valor;
    }
    else if (this->tipo == sub)
    {
        return "Sub: " + this->valor;
    }
    else if (this->tipo == mult)
    {
        return "Mult: " + this->valor;
    }
    else if (this->tipo == divisao)
    {
        return "Div: " + this->valor;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Token invalido: " + this->valor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos erros está acontecendo no método `Scanner::getToken()`.
A assinatura do método indica que será retornado um objeto do tipo `Token`, no entanto, na implementação do método está sendo retornado um `new Token();`, isto é um ponteiro para `Token`.

Nesta situação, existem algumas soluções:

- Alterar a assinatura do método para retornar um `Token*` invés de `Token`.
- Alterar o retorno do método para retornar uma variável alocada estaticamente(remover o `new` do `return`).

O outro erro, é devido a comparação no `while`, que pode ser realizada criando o método `getValor();`

**main.cpp**

```
Scanner *scan = new Scanner("(48 + 30)/2 (15 - 10)");
Token tk = scan->getToken();

while(tk.getValor() != ""){
    cout<<tk.print()<<endl;
    tk = scan->getToken();
}
```

**Token.h**

```
class Token
{
    private:
            string valor;
            TipoToken tipo;
    public:
            Token(TipoToken tipo, string valor);
            string print();
            string getValor();
            TipoToken getTipo();
};
```

**Token.cpp**

```
string Token::getValor(){
    return this->valor;
}

TipoToken Token::getTipo()
{
    return this->tipo;
}
```

Comment: Eu diria que retornar um objeto `Token` por valor também seria uma opção, mas precisaria fazer uma chamado ao construtor de `Token`, não ao `new`

Comment: Olá @Monari ou JeffersonQuesado, podemos continuar esse debate via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65969/could-not-convert-erro-ao-retornar-objeto)?